# How can i properly align Arabic text using the Corona SDK?

Tags: coronasdk, arabic, text-alignment

How can I properly align Arabic text using the Corona SDK? I tried using a native text box but when I do that I cannot use the touch event listener to flip through pages.

Comment: Welcome to SO - it's generally a good idea to show what research you've done, and provide a bit more specificity to your question - this will encourage more people to help out.

Answer (score 1):

In daily build 1143, multi-line display.newTexts support alignment, so you can right align those.  Daily builds are however, only available to Pro and Enterprise subscribers.